# how can i create this type of layout in css with grid

Tags: css, css-grid

i want to make an layout using css grid with responsive media query but im not sure how to make this

here mobile view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBVxM.png)

here desktop view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CNUo.png)

for desktop view i can use `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);`

how can i make it look like in mobile view ?

my HTML markup

```
  <li className="invoice-list">
      <h1>#{x.id}</h1>
      <p>{x.paymentDue}</p>
      <h1>{x.clientName}</h1>
      <h1>${x.total}</h1>
      <button>{x.status}</button>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably would make more sense to use flexbox in this case. Use `flex-flow: row;` for the desktop version, and `flex-flow: column wrap;` for the mobile version.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(25, 25, 40);
  padding: 3em;
}

.invoice-list {
  background: rgb(40, 40, 70);
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 7em;
}
.pending {
  text-align: left;
  color: orange;
  background: rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.pending::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.invoice-list > * {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .invoice-list {
    /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr; */
    flex-flow: row;
    height: 3em;
  }
  .invoice-list > * {
    align-self: right;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="invoice-list">
  <b>#PC4066</b>
  <span>Due 28 Jul 2021</span>
  <b>$130.00</b>
  <b>John</b>
  <button class="pending">Pending</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use a mix of `css-grid` and `flexbox`

You create two rows, twos columns with `css-grid`.
Then with `flexbox` you can `justify-content:flex-start;` for the contents in the first column and `justify-content:flex-end;` for the items in the second column.

There are a lot of online minigames to learn `flexbox` if you're not already familiar with it!

**Here is a quick example :**

```css
.invoice-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "tl tr" "bl br";
}

.id {
  grid-area: "tl";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.paymentDue {
  grid-area: "tr";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
  
  .bottom-left{
    grid-area: "bl";
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  
  .button{
   grid-area: "br";
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   align-items:flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<li class="invoice-list">
      <h1 class="id">#{x.id}</h1>
      <p class="paymentDue">{x.paymentDue}</p>
      <div class="bottom-left">
        <h1>{x.clientName}</h1>
        <h1>${x.total}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>
          {x.status}
        </button>
      </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: i tried using this but it way to many overhead and clutter my HTML markup so i was looking simple solution. i updated my html markup

Comment: @lemon69 this does not add any HTML ... you can do exactly this with 6 divs, including the one that wraps the 5 elements. This is pure css.

Comment: ok, i will try without cluttering my markup

Comment: @lemon69 no that you have added your code, there is a lot of problem in your markup. You should not use `list` with different elements. In general, do not use a list to organize your HTML. If you want to achieve what is in the image you gave, you should use div and not default tags. Tags are great for very simple things, here you should style everything with css.